# How to show Kibana Visualization dashboard in Website?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a csv file and I have passed through the ElasitcSearch and create a dashboard in Kibana. Is there any way to display this dashboard in the website. Like any bootstrap kind of script available? Or Any other way to embed in Django or Flask frame work

Comment: Why are you using kibana if you  are planning to have ur own front end , just use the elasticsearch API in ur front end and display the results the way u want

Answer (score 2):

From your dashboard, you can click the `Share` button which will provide you a  piece of html that you can add to your own page, such as:

```
<iframe src="http://yourkibanaserver:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/General-Dashboard?embed=true&_g=(refreshInterval:(display:'5%20minutes',pause:!f,section:2,value:300000),time:(from:now-4h,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),options:(darkTheme:!t),panels:!((col:1,id:total-duration-ms,panelIndex:1,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:visualization),(col:7,id:alarm-duration-ms,panelIndex:2,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:visualization),(col:1,id:Alarm-2-s,panelIndex:3,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:7,id:Alarm-1,panelIndex:4,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'General%20Dashboard',uiState:(P-1:(vis:(colors:('Average%20durationms':%2370DBED))),P-2:(vis:(colors:('Average%20alarm_duration_ms':%23B7DBAB))),P-3:(vis:(colors:('Average%20elapsed_time':%23F4D598))),P-4:(vis:(colors:('Average%20elapsed_time':%23F29191)))))" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you it works, If the Kibana have username and password then how to do?